# Multiclient Server Implementation in C

Tags: c, client-server

I am trying to implement multi client server using C. I have write code for server and client is a software that will continuously send some packet to server. Server will read the packet and process it. I am trying for 5 connection at a time to server. But there is some problem with server code that I have written due to which I can not connect 5 client to server. Exact  Problem is that when client is trying to connect with server it gets connection for but when I close client software and try to start again it is not getting connection. Following is my code for server side. can anybody help me regarding this problem.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/file.h>


int sock;                       /* The socket file descriptor for our "listening"socket */
int connectlist[15];            /* Array of connected sockets so we know who we are talking to */
fd_set socks;                   /* Socket file descriptors we want to wake up for, using select() */
int highsock = 1;               /* Highest #'d file descriptor, needed for select() */
struct sockaddr_in client_address[5];
unsigned int clientLength = sizeof(client_address) ;
#define PORTNO      (int)49153
int port;                       /* The port number after conversion from ascport */
struct sockaddr_in server_address; /* bind info structure */
int reuse_addr = 1;  
struct timeval timeout;         /* Timeout for select */
int readsocks;                  /* Number of sockets ready for reading */
int err = 0 ;

#define BACKLOG         (int)10

void deal_with_data(int listnum /* Current item in connectlist for for loops */)
{
    //Here I am trying to read packet from client s/w and process it
}

void setnonblocking(int sock)
{
    int opts;
    opts = fcntl(sock,F_GETFL);
    if (opts < 0) 
    {
        printf("fcntl(F_GETFL)_error");
        exit(0);
    }
    opts = (opts | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fcntl(sock,F_SETFL,opts) < 0) 
    {
        printf("fcntl(F_SETFL)_error");
        exit(0);
    }
    return;
}

void build_select_list() 
{
    int listnum;         /* Current item in connectlist for for loops */
    FD_ZERO(&socks);
    FD_SET(sock,&socks);
    for (listnum = 0; listnum < 5; listnum++) 
    {
        if (connectlist[listnum] != 0) 
        {
            FD_SET(connectlist[listnum],&socks);
            if (connectlist[listnum] > highsock)
                highsock = connectlist[listnum];
        }
    }
}

void handle_new_connection() {
    int listnum;         /* Current item in connectlist for for loops */
    int connection; /* Socket file descriptor for incoming connections */
    connection = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address[highsock], &clientLength);
    if (connection < 0) 
    {
        printf("accept_error");
        exit(0);
    }
    setnonblocking(connection);
    for (listnum = 0; (listnum < 5) && (connection != -1); listnum ++)
        if (connectlist[listnum] == 0) 
        {
            printf("\nConnection accepted:   FD=%d; Slot=%d\n",
                connection,listnum);
            printf("Connection accepted from %s\n",inet_ntoa(client_address[highsock].sin_addr));
            connectlist[listnum] = connection;
            connection = -1;

        }
    if (connection != -1) 
    {
        printf("\nNo room left for new client.\n");
        write(connection,"Sorry, this server is too busy.Try again later!\r\n",80);
        close(connection);
    }
    printf("return from handle_new_connection\n");
}

void read_socks(void)
{
    int listnum;         /* Current item in connectlist for for loops */
    if (FD_ISSET(sock,&socks))
        handle_new_connection();
    for (listnum = 0; listnum < 5; listnum++) 
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(connectlist[listnum],&socks))
        {
            //printf("read_socks2\n");
            deal_with_data(listnum);
        }
    }
}

int main (/*int argc, char *argv[]*/)
{
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock < 0) 
    {
        printf("socket_error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse_addr,sizeof(reuse_addr));
    setnonblocking(sock);

    memset((char *) &server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_address.sin_port = htons(port);

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address,sizeof(server_address)) < 0 ) 
    {
        printf("bind_error");
        close(sock);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((err = listen(sock,10)) == -1)
    {
        printf("listen_error");
    }

    highsock = sock;
    memset((char *) &connectlist, 0, sizeof(connectlist));

    while (1) 
    { /* Main server loop - forever */
        build_select_list();
        timeout.tv_sec = 2;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        readsocks = select(highsock+2, &socks, (fd_set *) 0,(fd_set *) 0, &timeout);
        if (readsocks < 0) 
        {
            printf("select_error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (readsocks == 0) 
        {
            printf(".");
            fflush(stdout);
        } 
        else
        {   
            read_socks();
        }
    } /* while(1) */
} /* main */
```

Comment: You need to detect when a client disconnect and free that clients place in `client_address`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your main loop doesn't exit when the socket has been closed by the client. This means that it cannot accept new connections. I would use `fork()` to do the processing of the data from the socket, and the `main()` function to accept connections and `fork()` the process. Also, you need to have some code which will kill the `fork()`ed (i.e. to check if the client has disconnected in the `fork()`ed process) process (since it won't close by itself and it takes up memory).

EDIT:

Ok, I can't find a call to `recv()` in your program. According the the [recv(3) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/recv) it will `return 0` if the client disconnect "gracefully" and `return -1` and set `errno` to `ECONNRESET` if the client forcefully disconnected. In order to use fork, I would (in the `main()` function) wrap your while loop in this:

```
int childpid = fork();
if(childpid == -1) {
       printf("Could not fork process");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else if(childpid == 0) { /* in child process*/
       while(/* check if the socket has been closed */) {
               /* While loop stuff */
       }
       /* free up memory */
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And your main function should be in a loop, waiting for new connections.

N.B. I have not tested any of this code, so it might not work. But if you read the man pages for `fork(3)` and `recv(3)` it should work.

Comment: Hey thanks for suggestion, but can you just elaborate your answer because I am new to this fork concept. It will be better if you tell me where should I use this fork and how. thank in advance.

Comment: Updated answer to give an example.

Comment: Also, if you decide to use `read()` instead of `recv()` to read from the socket, the same rules apply. (see the [read(3) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/read) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you better off using something off the shelf like Apache and customize it as necessary?